# Почему R.strings и getJSONObject не работают внутри setText

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему строка

```java
result_info.setText(R.string.result_info);
```

работает прекрасно, и поле result_info получает значение result_info из файла stings.xml

А вот строка

```java
result_info.setText(R.string.result_info + jsonObject.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp"));
```

Почему-то не работает и выводит следующее:

```
21317550921.63
```

Файл strings.xml содержит:

```xml
<string name="result_info">Температура: </string>
```

Comment: А что содержит тот jsonObjekt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `R.string.result_info` - это не строка, а идентификатор ресурса (число типа `int`).
Во втором случае выполняется арифметическая операция сложения этого числа с числом из json и выводится результат.
Нужно получить строку из ресурсов по этому идентификатору, тогда будет ожидаемая конкатенация:

```java
String string = context.getString(R.string.result_info);
result_info.setText(string + jsonObject.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp"));
```